# Stream closed error when adding attachment to MailMessage

Tags: c#, .net, email

I use the following code to attach a file to an email message.

```
msg = new MailMessage();

    using (strMem = new MemoryStream((byte[])attDr["filedata"]))
    {
        using (strWriter = new StreamWriter(strMem))
        {
            strWriter.Flush(); strMem.Position = 0;
            using (attachment = new Attachment(strMem, attDr["filename"].ToString()))
            {
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }
    }

...
...
msg.Send();  //Error: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

The error message is: //Error: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream

Im guessing that the "USING" statement closes the stream when exiting the block. But why doesnt "Attacments.Add()" make its own copy of the stream?

Comment: Welcome to the magic world of the `StreamWriter`. It always closes the wrapped `Stream`. One of the wonderful design quirks in the .NET framework :-)

Comment: It's just because at the end of using block it dispose the object attachment. But attachment is use by msg. so....

Comment: The `msg` variable is never declared. Nor does the `MailMessage` class contain any `Send()` method.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The Send() method is going to access the attachments to embed them into the mail message.  That goes kaboom here, the memory stream was disposed.  You need to move the Send() call inside of the *using* statements so the stream doesn't get disposed until *after* the message is sent.

Mentioning that *using* isn't necessary here because a memory stream doesn't have any unmanaged resources that need to be disposed always gets me into trouble at SO.  So I won't bring that up.

Comment: I love how you don't bring that up. :)

Answer (score 17):

One solution I found to this when I was dealing with  a scenario where the MailMessage  was being created separate from the sending and potentially with multiple attachments was to use a List of MemoryStream objects

```
// Tuple contains displayName and byte[] content for attachment in this case
List<Tuple<string,byte[]>> attachmentContent;
MailMessage email = BuildNativeEmail(requestObject, out attachmentContent);
List<MemoryStream> streams = new List<MemoryStream>();
foreach(Tuple<string,byte[]> attachment in attachmentContent)
{
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(attachment.Item2);
    email.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(m, attachment.Item1));
    streams.add(m);
}

// client represents a System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient object
client.Send(email);

foreach(MemoryStream stream in streams)
{
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes.Its true.Using statement closes the stream when exiting the block.

Don't use "**Using**" statement.After sending email call *dispose()* method for **Attachments**.

```
...
...
msg.Send();

msg.Attachments.ToList().ForEach(x => x.ContentStream.Dispose());
```

You can also use the same way for **AlternateView**.

```
...
...
msg.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);

...
msg.Send();
...
if (alternateView != null) {
    mail.AlternateViews.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
using (strMem = new MemoryStream((byte[])attDr["filedata"]))
{
    using (strWriter = new StreamWriter(strMem))
    {
        strWriter.Flush(); strMem.Position = 0;
        using (attachment = new Attachment(attDr["filename"].ToString()))
        {
            strMem.CopyTo(attachment.ContentStream);
            msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed USING from the row where I create the Attachment, but still the same error. Also strMem did not support "CopyTo" so I had to use strMem.WriteTo(attachment.ContentStream);

Comment: Im at loss what is triggering the error. I do suppose though that USING is involved in some way!    :)

Comment: Is is USING that invoke "Dispose" and dispose your resources, don't use Dispose before sending your email and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
List<MemoryStream> streams = new List<MemoryStream>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    file.CopyTo(ms);
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, file.FileName));
    streams.Add(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
SendEmail(mail); //smtp.Send(mail) with other configurations
foreach (MemoryStream stream in streams) stream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the using on the **MailMessage**, it will internally dispose of the streams that make up the attachments

```
using(var msg = new MailMessage())
{
    ...
    ...
    var attachment = new Attachment(strMem, filename,contentType);
    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    ...
    ...             
    msg.Send();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. The `MailMessage` class does not have any `Send()` method.

Comment: ha, you are right. My point was the using block, the original post had send on the msg, which perhaps could be an ex method for SmtpClient.Send(msg)