# Objects implementing IDisposable using another IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I try to develop an application in C# and have some concerns with `MailMessage` object:

it implements `IDisposable` interface, so I use it within `using` statement. So it implicitly calls `Dispose` method after. Now, using that object I need to add attachments, which I have converted to `byte[]` object and I add them as stream. Here's part of code to have better view:

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage("john.smith@gmail.com"){
    MemoryStream stream;
    //here I pass byte array to the stream and create an attachemnt
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "name.xyz"));

    using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("server.com", port))
    {
        // send message
    }
}
```

Now, I have one resource unmanaged: `Stream` object. I can't close it (so can't call `Dispose` method) right after setting attachments, because I'd get an error when sending message, because it uses the stream while sending.

So, I need to get rid of it later, which I do after sending. That's the code in second `using`:

```
try
{
    client.Send(messgae);
}
finally
{
    if(stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

Now the question: `Dispose` method of `MailMesssage` frees all resources used by that object. My `Stream` object is one of the resources, isn't it? So, when `using(MailMessage...` terminates it should manage also my `Stream` object, shouldn't it? So I wouldn't need to dispose of my `Stream` object manually.

EDIT:

Suggested approach:

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage("john.smith@gmail.com"){
    using(MemoryStream stream = ...)
    {
        //here I pass byte array to the stream and create an attachemnt
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "name.xyz"));

        using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("server.com", port))
        {
            // send message
        }
    }
}
```

But the questions stays: `MailMessage` uses this `Stream` - so, do we still need to manage `Stream` on our own?

Comment: you need to use using for MemoryStream too, Steam isn't part of MailMessage

Comment: You may have a read on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065168/does-disposing-streamreader-close-the-stream. I´m not sure if that applies to `MailMessage` also but according to what you wrote I suspect it does. Also here´s another article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252271/stream-closed-error-when-adding-attachment-to-mailmessage

Comment: The `Dispose` implementation for `MemoryStream` basically does nothing. Is is completely safe not to `Dispose` of `MemoryStream` instances.

Comment: @spender While that is probably true (didn't bother to check) it means that developers should get to know the **implementation** of whatever classes they use. Not only is it impossible, it goes against the encapsulation principle. Given an interface, you shouldn't be bothered to get yourself familiar with the concrete implementation. So even if the specific implementation of Dispose in MemoryStream does nothing (at the moment, implementation details like that might change in the future!), I would still not recommend not to dispose it. If something implements IDisposable it should be disposed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed. It's a bad habit and bad example not to dispose, especially when dev#2 comes in and replaces the MemoryStream with a FileStream (for example). However... it is safe to say that the implementation of MemoryStream will never change as it will never need to rely on unmanaged resources, as is the case for most other streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference documentation you don't need to when you are using `using`.

[Mail Message](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs) disposes [Attachment Collection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/AttachmentCollection.cs%20%22Attachment%20Collection), which then disposes all its attachements.

---

Regarding, should we take or rely on this approach then I totally agree with Zohar on

> Disposing of an IDisposable should be expressed in your code, either by calling Dispose explicitly or with the using statement.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. How did you find this answer, since it requires some browsing through objects and nested `Dispose` methods :)

Comment: Google (mail message reference source) -> Ctrl + F (Dispose)  -> Ctrl + F (AttachmentCollection) and finally Ctrl + F (Dispose) again.

Answer (score 3):

Why not dispose the stream after the message is sent?

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage("john.smith@gmail.com"))
{
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //here I pass byte array to the stream and create an attachemnt
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "name.xyz"));

        using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("server.com", port))
        {
        // send message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I guess answer to my question is no... :)

Comment: I don't know and I can't be bothered to check. Not only is it an implementation detail, it also moves the responsibility of disposing your stream to another class. Anyway, as I wrote in my comment to spender, Whenever you are dealing with an IDisposable, you should be disposing it, either by explicitly call Dispose or with the using statement. That guarantees proper disposing of your instance even in future .Net versions.

Comment: Ok, accepted answer is exactly what I needed. Can you give me your opinion on that? I think it will be crucial to my future habits :)

Comment: Already did. IMHO, disposing of an `IDisposable` should be expressed in your code, either by calling `Dispose` explicitly or with the using statement.
Trusting the implementation of classes you didn't build and have no control over is a naive approach. Again, this is my opinion only, and I might be wrong about it, However, I say better safe then sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage("john.smith@gmail.com")
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("server.com", port))
{
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "name.xyz"))
    client.Send(messgae);
}
```

If you put `MemoryStream` in `using` block, it will do the same thing as your `try/finally` block.