# Does each SMPT Attachment require a separate stream, when the file is created from a stream

Tags: c#, stream, smtp

I'm adding attachments to my email. The email is sent outside of the body/attachment creation method. Originally (when the function handled only one attachment) I had using(stream){attachment.add(stream..)}

Now that I loop trough up to 20 attachments, I keep the stream and close it, after the smtp.send() has been called.

The end result is, up to 20 file attachments of appropriate name and type are added, but only the first one has correct data and contents, any other file after it is blank and empty.

My question is, does each attachment require its own stream, so instead of me passing the one stream I'd just pass a List for all the files, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910652/1368562)

All the attachments are excel spreadsheets created using
ExcelOpenXmlWriter.WriteToStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in case of broken attachments created from stream, when multiple. It does require separate stream for each attachment. In my case I pass those around in a list, and close them after I send the email.